# calculating z transform of vector matlab

Tags: matlab, z-transform

Ive been reading the matlab guide of z-transform but cant find the solution.
How do you calculate the z-transfom of : x[n] = [5,6,9,7,2];?

ztrans([5,6,9,7,2],n,z);  (in mupad)

but this didnt give the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the actual command window, not mupad. Follow the examples to learn:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ztrans.html